# Как сделать из обычного файла разрежённый файл?

Tags: c, алгоритм, unix

Сейчас изучаю системный вызовы `read(), write(), lseek(output, count, SEEK_CUR), ftruncate(output, size)` в Unix и пытаюсь с их помощью сделать программу на си для превращения обычного в файла в [Разрежённый файл](https://wiki2.org/ru/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB+Milds.6), но не могу понять алгоритм действия/вызова этих функций :(

Comment: Найти ближайший нулевой байт, найти ближайший ненулевой байт, вызвать ftruncate для диапазона от первого нулевого до первого ненулевого, повторять в цикле до конца файла?

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, но как можно итерироваться по файлу и получать значение конкретного символа (сейчас открыл файл через open с флагами "rw", но после этого ступор) :(

Comment: Замапить (mmap) болезгого в оперативку и бежать как по обычному массиву.

Comment: Судя по [man 2 fallocate](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fallocate) и описанию  [тут](https://ru.manpages.org/fallocate/2) достаточно открыть c `O_RDWR`, посмотреть fstat-ом размер и вызвать `fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE | FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE, 0, size)`

Comment: Если fallocate не доступен (или текущая FS его не поддерживает), то придется делать копию. Читаете исходный файл и переписываете ненулевые байты в копию (буфер побольше не забудьте сделать или вообще лучше mmap-нуть исходный файл). Нулевые читаете и подсчитываете (например, в переменной `len`) и встретив опять ненулевой байт, вызываете `lseek(out_fd, len, SEEK_CUR)` (см. [man lseek](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html)

Comment: И, да, (отвечая на ваш неожиданный вопрос в комментарии) файл читается вызовом [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) (а пишется [write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html))  (и в [open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) нет флагов "rw" (с fopen перепутали))